# Using lettrine with mathptmx

Tags: fonts, lettrine, mathptmx

I found a [template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/journal-article) that uses the `lettrine` package with `mathpazo`. I want to use `mathptmx`, but when I use `lettrine` to make a large first letter, the *second* letter appears capitalized. The trick seems to be that the template uses the `[sc]` option for `mathpazo`, but I cannot find a comparable option for `mathptmx`. How can I have a large first letter with a lower-case second letter using `mathptmx`?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}    
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
% I get the expected behavior if I use \usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} instead
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}    
\section{Title}
\lettrine[nindent=0em,lines=3]{O} nce    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Thanks for posting a compilable example. You should write either \lettrine[nindent=0em,lines=3]{L}{orem} ipsum` or `\lettrine[nindent=0em,lines=3]{L}{}orem ipsum`. The former choice is more traditional, as it renders the remainder of the first word in small-caps (not all-caps).

Comment: @Mico Thanks, that solved it! You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: @Mico That solution will work but the package does actually provide the facility to change the default setting for the font of the remainder of the first word. This is explained in the documentation. I don't know if there are any cases in which the results will differ but I think it is a little clearer what is going on this way. See my answer. (Your comment wasn't here when I was writing that answer.)

Comment: @cfr - My guess is that the OP didn't know (or had forgotten) that the `\lettrine` command takes *two* mandatory arguments. Your solution, which redefines `\LettrineTextFont`, is certainly more elegant than inserting an empty group.

Comment: @Mico The OP certainly didn't know, he incorrectly assumed the template knew what it was doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `lettrine` typesets the remainder of the first word, which is supposed to be the second mandatory argument to `\lettrine`, in small-caps. You can change this using

```
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\upshape}
```

to get standard, upright lowercase instead. Note that this is happening with only the second letter of the first word in your case because you have not surrounded `nce` in curly brackets (`{nce}`).

Here's the corrected code with the command to get lower case in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
% I get the expected behavior if I use \usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} instead
\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\upshape}
\begin{document}
\section{Title}
\lettrine[nindent=0em,lines=3]{O}{nce} upon a time, there was a little girl and a large dragon. They lived in a beautiful forest but the little girl was terrified of the large dragon and the large dragon was terrified of the little girl.
\end{document}
```

[image: lettrine with lower case]